# Add Sdk (Pushwoosh SDK)

Tags: ios, sdk, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

I probably have the simplest question in the world. Here goes:

I am using pushwoosh for push notifications for my ios app. Basically, you just have to simply add Push NotificationsSDK to your project. Here is the link to the sdk: https://github.com/shaders/push-notifications-sdk/tree/master/SDK/iPhone-ARC

However, I can't get this to work. The only thing I can think of is that I don't know how to add a SDK to my project (a Master-Detail application).

The error is that whenever I try to import a file, like pushnotificationmanager.h, it gives me an error that it does not recognize the file. (Hence, why I think I am not adding the sdk correctly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drag the folder "Classes" or all files in that foler to your project. Tick on the "Copy to project" when Xcode's popup window asks you. Then it should be ok to import the .h files and follow the integration guide.

DO NOT drag the xcodeproj file to your project. Use the source files.

Comment: May be they just forget to remove it. Who knows ;)

Comment: Remember to add CoreLocation.framework to your "Link Binary With Libraries" in Build Phases tab. I tried it and every goes well.

Comment: I checked the demo project files and there is another way to do it with the xcodeproj file. Drag the xcodeproj file to your project, then add `PushNotificationManager` in the Build Phases's Target Dependencies, then add `libPushNotificationManager.a` in the Link Binary With Libraries. The two way should be the same here.

Comment: @onevcat 我是悉毅。Nice to meet you here! I got similar problem after I migrate my project to XCode 5. I will create another question to invite you to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this scenario several times when I add new phone for development. The provisioning file need be updated to include the new device. Then you need add new provisioning file to Xcode. Restart Xcode.

It works in my project. I am not sure does this it work in your scenario.